# Data persisted on the disk is not loaded by BootstrapCacheloader

Tags: persistence, ehcache

I am using `Ehcache` (quite older version 1.3), I have a requirement where my persisted data should be loaded in memory when my application restarts, I am using a custom `BootstrapCacheLoader` for this, in the load method of the loader when I iterate over the keys it returns me nothing, it is empty but I can see data stored in .data file.

I use `List<?> keys = mycache.getKeys();`

and I get `keys` (list) as empty.
Anything I am missing?

Comment: Please provide a http://www.sscce.org/. It is impossible to help you without being able to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Adding the java file which implements BootstrapCacheLoader and my ehcache.xml configuration file.